# XPATH Last element with certain class

Tags: xpath, ranorex

I have a date picker on my website,
It contains a list of  elements for each week
and then those include 7  elements for each day

2930311234

Now I'm trying to xpath find the last button with class "is-selected"
And I'd also like to go trough each week since I want the last possible date ( "is-selected" means avaible)

I've tried

```
.//div[#'available-dates-calendar']//table/?[last()='True']//button[last()='True']
```

But that gave me the first element...

Comment: how we will know what html structure of it looks a like?

Comment: Share your relevant html?

Answer (score 0):

For the last() condition to work, I think that you would have to use the spy to create a XPath query that finds all buttons.

When such a query is found, then you can use the last() condition to find the last in the list of items found.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use the [-1] identifier to grab the last element. So, instead of [last()='True'], use [-1].